# Python pptx insert a picture in a table cell

Tags: python, python-pptx

Is there a way to insert a picture inside a cell using pptx python?
I'm also thinking of finding the coordinate of the cell and adjust the numbers for inserting the picture, but can not find anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately not. Note that this is not a limitation of `python-pptx`, it is a limitation of PowerPoint in general. Only text can be placed in a table cell.

There is nothing stopping you from placing a picture shape *above* (in z-order) a table cell, which will *look* like the picture is inside. This is a common approach but unfortunately is somewhat brittle. In particular, the row height is not automatically adjusted to "fit" the picture and changes in the content of cells in prior rows can cause lower rows to "move down" and no longer be aligned with the picture. So this approach has some drawbacks.

Another possible approach is to use a picture as the *background* for a cell (like you might use colored shading or a texture). There is no API support for this in `python-pptx` and it's not without its own problems, but might be an approach worth considering.